# Spring batch unable to configure 2 readers and split jobs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

Need help to understand what constitutes as a step and a job and how to configure them as a spring batch program. Scenario is .

```
 <pre>
  <datasource name="xyz">
       <searchcriteria name="ab" parafield1="content_i" parafield2="supplier-1"/>
       <searchcriteria name="ab" parafield1="content_i" parafield2="supplier-1"/>
       <searchcriteria .../>
      </datasource>
  </pre>
```

1. Read a set of search parameters from  an external XML file as above.
2. For every search criteria, step 3 and step 4 has to be done.
3. System as to hit a SOAP service which might return with 10K odd records.
4. For every 250 records (endpoint capacity constraint) in 10K odd results,  I have to hit another SOAP service and the results should written to 3 csv files, 2 of which are consolidated and 1 file for every record (250 files). Writing of 2 files and 1 csv file can be in parallel.

Design decisions

1. I cannot have a one job launcher for every search, as there is capacity constraints at the source. No no parallel search.
2. No DB involvement, hence no need of metadata DB
3. No restart ability required. It is always from the beginning.

Question (edited)

Would like to have XML reader in the first step  (no processing , no writer) and for every search (read in first step), how should I repeat step 2 where again I read (call services) and generate CSV files (split between 2 writers) ?

Using Spring boot 2.0.4.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would love to help but that's too broad with 5 questions at the same time. Try to narrow your question and provide a minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine: Question edited.

Comment: Have you checked out using tasklets ? Here is a quick tutorial that somewhat resembles the described scenario: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-batch-tasklet-chunk